# Multiple trained models vs Multple features and one model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to build a regression based M/L model using tensorflow.

I am trying to estimate an **object's ETA** based on the following:

- distance from target
- distance from target (X component)
- distance from target (Y component)
- speed

The object travels on specific journeys. This could be represented as from A->B or from A->C or from D->F (POINT 1 -> POINT 2). There are 500 specific journeys (between a set of points).
These journeys aren't completely straight lines, and every journey is different (ie. the shape of the route taken).

I have two ways of getting around this problem:

1. I can have 500 different models with 4 features and one label(the training ETA data).
2. I can have 1 model with 5 features and one label.

My dilemma is that if I use option 1, that's added complexity, but will be more accurate as every model will be specific to each journey.

If I use option 2, the model will be pretty simple, but I don't know if it would work properly. The new feature that I would add are **originCode**+ **destinationCode**. Unfortunately these are not quantifiable in order to make any numerical sense or pattern - they're just text that define the journey (journey A->B, and the feature would be 'AB').

Is there some way that I can use one model, and categorize the features so that one feature is just a 'grouping' feature (in order separate the training data with respect to the journey.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of the route "shape"?  Seems like some interesting features could be gleaned from that.

Comment: Also, how many "trips" do you have per route in your data?

Comment: It seems that "time spent on route so far" would also be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In ML, I believe that option 2 is **generally** the better option. We prefer general models rather than tailoring many models to specific tasks, as that gets dangerously close to hardcoding, which is what we're trying to get away from by using ML!

I think that, depending on the training data you have available, and the model size, a one-hot vector could be used to describe the starting/end points for the model. Eg, say we have 5 points (ABCDE), and we are going from position B to position C, this could be represented by the vector:

> 0100000100

as in, the first five values correspond to the origin spot whereas the second five are the destination. It is also possible to combine these if you want to reduce your input feature space to:

> 01100

There are other things to consider, as Scott has said in the comments:

- How much data do you have? Maybe the feature space will be too big this way, I can't be sure. If you have enough data, then the model will intuitively learn the general distances (not actually, but intrinsically in the data) between datapoints. 
  If you have enough data, you might even be able to accurately predict between two points you don't have data for!
- If it does come down to not having enough data, then finding representative features of the journey will come into use, ie. length of journey, shape of the journey, elevation travelled etc. Also a metric for distance travelled **from** the origin could be useful.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to lean toward individual models.  This is because, for a given position along a given route and a constant speed, the ETA is a deterministic function of time.  If one moves monotonically closer to the target along the route, it is also a deterministic function of distance to target.  Thus, there is no information to transfer from one route to the next, i.e. "lumping" their parameters offers no a priori benefit.  This is assuming, of course, that you have several "trips" worth of data along each route (i.e. (distance, speed) collected once per minute, or some such).  If you have only, say, one datum per route then lumping the parameters is a must.  However, in such a low-data scenario, I believe that including a dummy variable for "which route" would ultimately be fruitless, since that would introduce a number of parameters that rivals the size of your dataset.

As a side note, NEITHER of the models you describe could handle new routes.  I would be inclined to build an individual model per route, data quantity permitting, and a single model neglecting the route identity entirely just for handling new routes, until sufficient data is available to build a model for that route.